# openssl 1.1.1 Configure failure

Tags: openssl

I have a big question about failure on OpenSSL configuring.
I'd installed ActiveState Perl (5.28) and NASM. Then I'd cloned the OpenSSL repository (branch OpenSSL_1_1_1-stable) into C:/Respositories/openssl directory.
I tried configure openssl build for VC-WIN32A target platform. Tests on both computers (Win10 OS) gave me same results:

```
C:\Repositories\openssl>perl Configure VC-WIN32
Configuring OpenSSL version 1.1.1h-dev (0x10101080L) for VC-WIN32
Using os-specific seed configuration
Can't locate Win32/Console.pm in @INC (you may need to install the Win32::Console module) (@INC contains: C:/Repositories/openssl/util/perl C:/Perl64/site/lib C:/Perl64/lib) at C:/Perl64/lib/ActivePerl/Config.pm line 400.
Compilation failed in require at C:/Perl64/site/lib/ExtUtils/MakeMaker.pm line 9.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at C:/Perl64/site/lib/ExtUtils/MakeMaker.pm line 9.
Compilation failed in require at C:/Perl64/site/lib/IPC/Cmd.pm line 235.
```

Comment: configuring 1.0.2u was successful...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks as though this is an error in the ActiveState Perl software - the module is referenced in the supplied Config.pm file, but isn't supplied in the distribution and doesn't appear to be build-able or retrievable from it (disclaimer - I don't have any Perl experience).

I commented out the relevant entries since they only seem to set screen attributes:

```perl
# Prevent calling Win32::Console::DESTROY on a STDOUT handle
my $console;
sub _warn {
    my($msg) = @_;
    unless (-t STDOUT) {
    print "\n$msg\n";
    return;
    }
#    require Win32::Console;
#    unless ($console) {
#   $console = Win32::Console->new(Win32::Console::STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE());
#    }
    my($col,undef) = 80; #$console->Size;
    print "\n";
#    my $attr = $console->Attr;
#    $console->Attr($Win32::Console::FG_RED | $Win32::Console::BG_WHITE);
    for (split(/\n/, "$msg")) {
    $_ .= " " while length() < $col-1;
    print "$_\n";
    }
#    $console->Attr($attr);
    print "\n";
}
```

...and that progressed me to the stage where Perl says that I don't have nmake on my path, but I do and ignoring that warning I proceed and can build.